# Working with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have a question that I am looking for the answer to.  I am not really understanding NSNumberFormatter.  I've stared at the documentation for a while, and can't seem to understand why I can't get setMinimum (or setMaximum) to work at all.

Here is the code I am using:

```
NSNumberFormatter* numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setMinimum:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"]];
[numberFormatter setMaximum:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"]];
[numberFormatter setMultiplier:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1]];
//[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:OVER9000];
NSLog(@"%@, %@", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.123456789]], [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.8]]);
```

I've been playing around with stuff like that and my plan was that something would happen, but it really doesn't look like anything is going on (i.e. in the console, I get 1, 1)...

Comment: At least he's polite. We've had a lot worse.

Comment: This is my first time communicating with the internet.  I am still wrestling with the fact that you are actual people.  I mostly just read these when google gives them to me.  Also sometimes I spend time on the internet with people playing Xbox, or foruming about it, but they are much less friendly or like actual people.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: to get a number from a string, but only if it above a certain value.  Also to get an answer to a question that I don't yet have the answer to.

Comment: Either this guy honestly doesn't understand the Internet, or he's just a plain troll. I'm kind of leaning towards troll here.

Comment: This is sad.  I was trying to ask for help to understand how to properly use setMinimum.  The docs do not seem particularly descriptive here.  It may also be the case that I do not understand them properly.  I am not feeling to well now, and am going to go eat lunch.

Comment: Most voted to close before you actually added content to the question. Now you need to wait a bit for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't actually ask a question here's a link about [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Next time ask a question and you can get more help.